# Reindex error with searchkick — Searchkick::ImportError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I get this error when attempting to reindex with the Searchkick on production app with heroku

```
Searchkick::ImportError: Searchkick::ImportError
```

The command below is being used to reindex

```
heroku run rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Chapter
```

Chapter Model

```
class Chapter < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchkick word_start: [:title, :body], highlight: [:body]
end
```

Here's the error

```
        server:hrsimpleV3.0 justinMgrant$ heroku run rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Chapter
    Running rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Chapter on boiling-harbor-8117... up, run.1302
    Starting up a new ElasticSearch client with
    Scoped order and limit are ignored, it's forced to be batch order and batch size
      Chapter Load (12.5ms)  SELECT  "chapters".* FROM "chapters"  ORDER BY "chapters"."id" ASC LIMIT 1000
      Chapter Import (345.2ms)  {"count":8,"exception":["Searchkick::ImportError","Searchkick::ImportError"]}
    rake aborted!
    Searchkick::ImportError: Searchkick::ImportError
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/searchkick-1.0.2/lib/searchkick/index.rb:76:in `block in import'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/searchkick-1.0.2/lib/searchkick/index.rb:68:in `each'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/searchkick-1.0.2/lib/searchkick/index.rb:68:in `import'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/searchkick-1.0.2/lib/searchkick/logging.rb:47:in `block in import_with_instrumentation'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/searchkick-1.0.2/lib/searchkick/logging.rb:46:in `import_with_instrumentation'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/searchkick-1.0.2/lib/searchkick/index.rb:193:in `block in import_scope'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:124:in `find_in_batches'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/querying.rb:9:in `find_in_batches'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/searchkick-1.0.2/lib/searchkick/index.rb:192:in `import_scope'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/searchkick-1.0.2/lib/searchkick/index.rb:168:in `reindex_scope'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/searchkick-1.0.2/lib/searchkick/model.rb:51:in `searchkick_reindex'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/searchkick-1.0.2/lib/searchkick/tasks.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    Tasks: TOP => searchkick:reindex
```

Comment: This error occurs while the SQL command runs and before anything ever gets indexed in Elasticsearch. Can you show some more code, i.e. the method where you call `reindex` for instance?

Comment: I'm following the instructions from the searchkick gem.  They gave instructions to put searchkick in model then index in rails console with Chapter.reindex

Comment: Interesting. Do you have a bigger stack trace? if not, can you enable more logging and share?

Comment: Just added entire error message

Comment: Thanks, you should have also left the previous one as it was informative.

Comment: My bad, the others are back.  Thank you.

Comment: Can you try to define your Chapter active record just with `searchkick` and nothing else (i.e. no `word_start` or `highlight`)? Also you might want to try using the `accept_danger` parameter in the `reindex` call, [more info here](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#100)

Comment: Thanks for your help on this one.  I figured it out, it was my error, I had a require command in my lib/tasks/elasticsearch.rake file.  Removed it and everything went well.

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured it out!

Comment: I spoke too soon.  I fixed the error locally but found a similar error on production.  I'll update the post.

Comment: Exact same error. Have you checked your `lib/tasks/elasticsearch.rake` file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97676/discussion-between-justin-grant-and-val).

Comment: I've answered in the chat.